# Create a function that displays all the different combinaison of two digits between 00 and 99 by ascending order ( C programming)

Tags: c

so i was working on the school 42 subjects on my own, and i dont fully understand the code here.

I understand that this part is used to print the result on the screen

```
 void  ft_putchar(char c)
{
  write(1, &c, 1);
}
```

and that the following part is the setup of the limit and the incrementation, but i have my first question here :

Why does i starts at '-1' ?

My second question is concerning the division and modulus part, i dont understand much here, for example,how do the '-1' from the beginning becomes "00 01" ?

For the last part if i understand correctly it just adds a ',' and ' ' evrywhere to separate the combinaisons except at the very end.

```
#include <unistd.h>
    
void  ft_putchar(char c)
{
  write(1, &c, 1);
}

void ft_print_comb2(void)
{
  int i;
  int j;
  i = -1 ;
  while (++i <= 98)
  {
    j = i;
    while (++j <= 99)
    {
      ft_putchar((char)(i/10) + '0');
      ft_putchar((char)(i%10) + '0');
      ft_putchar(' ');
      ft_putchar((char)(j/10) + '0');
      ft_putchar((char)(j%10) + '0');
      
      
      if ( (i != 98))
      {
        ft_putchar(',');
        ft_putchar(' ');
      }
      
    }
  }
}


int main()
{
  ft_print_comb2();
  return(0);
}
```

Comment: i starts at -1 because it is pre-incremented at the top of the loop, so it should be 0 after the pre-increment.  In the C family of languages, arrays start at 0 which allows addressing to be efficient and clear, although it often makes it harder for humans not familiar with this paradigm.  (Conversely, in an Excel spreadsheet, row 1 is often a header, and one starts the count at 2)

Answer (score 0):

ft_print_comb2 C00

> Why does i starts at '-1' ?

Because its incremented before the evaluation of the loop

```
 while (++i <= 98)
```

> how do the '-1' from the beginning becomes "00 01" ?

```
i = -1 ;
while (++i <= 98) // i is 0 now
{
    j = i; //j is equal to i (==0)
    while (++j <= 99) // j is 1 now
```

about the division you are saying that the first char (who is going to be < 98) is the second digit so you divide it by 10 to get it. And since you are working with ints the fraction gets cut off.

Ex:

```
i = 25
i/10 => 2.5 => 2
```

And % modulus does the same but for the 1st digit

```
i=49
i%10 => remainder of 49/10 => 9
```

Then you do `(char)` to convert from int to char although it's redundant since you have the `+ '0'` there

I hope you passed the piscine!